# ARC in iOS 6 versus in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to ARC. My issue is that if we create a `strong` type property on a view controller, we need to make it nil once the navigation controller's `popViewController` happens.

Normally, we would do that in `viewDidUnload`. But in iOS 6 it's deprecated.

So where do we make that object `nil`? Apple says to do it in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` but that method does not get called every time when we pop the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're popping/pushing between the same two view controllers, then the pointer in the UINavigationController shouldn't change as long as they don't get dealloc'ed. If they do get dealloc'ed then everything in them should get dealloc'ed too.  You may end up creating new copies of these view controllers but that shouldn't be a problem because you're only creating new copies if the old ones were already dealloc'ed.  The only way you can be retaining objects is if your view controllers (or objects within them) are referencing each other, causing them to be retained.

The difference between `strong` and `weak` is not that you need to manually set `strong` to nil.  Rather, a `strong` relationship will cause an object to be retained, while a `weak` will not.  That's why delegates are usually set to `weak` since you don't want a delegate retaining its parent (not parent exactly, but the object that it's a delegate of).

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about it. Your properties will all get set to `nil` automatically by the Objective-C runtime in `dealloc`. This is true of all properties, not just outlets on a view controller.

Comment: But in my app if i am switching between same viewController multiple time.App allocation size is getting increase and that leads to crash. I think its because of ARC.

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong, perhaps by creating multiple copies of your view controller. Of course, it won't be possible to help unless you post your code.

Comment: Code i cant put. But i am doing simple pop and push. By tap on a button i am moving to AViewController and AViewController has back button. i pressing that button just i am playing with these two button only

Answer (score 1):

You define a property `strong` if you want to keep ownership on the referenced object.

From what I can understand you probably need a weak property (when your object is released by someone else you don't need it and it can be deallocated) or maybe a workaround could be set it to nil in the `viewDidDisappear` method, but as Jim Puls said, without seeing you code mine are just educated guesses...